# How to scrape data using R from the Google Search Page (not links)

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-search

When you search something generic on google, such as the definition of a word, or even the budget of a film, google provides you with the result in a box right under the search bar.

For example, if you search "Avengers Movie Budget" it'll be right there below. Is there a way to access this data using R? I would not have the exact URL of the google search page because it is dependent on the term being searched. I tried using the following, which would searched "The Avengers Movie Budget" on Google.

```
 site <- getForm("http://www.google.com/search", hl="en",lr="", q="The Avengers Movie Budget",sep = ""), btnG="Search")
 info<-htmlTreeParse(site)
```

If you do that actually, you will see the budget appear in the box right under the search tab. I then tried to find the budget within "info", but it is no where in there. Is there another way to do this? Thanks